How to process many ranges with the same nameless lambda?
I have some nameless lambda function which I need to apply to many ranges and don't like to repeat it to avoid code duplication (it consists of 5+ lines of code).
What is simplest way to implement this?
I want to have something like in the code below with some reservation:

I'd like to have lambda at the end of the arguments list like in most std algorithms.
I'd be more happy with syntax for_each_range({r1,r2,r3},lambda), but I can't figure out how to get these { } working here. The std::initializer_list seems to be not my way, since it requires const data and I have to change the values in the ranges.

#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

template<typename Func, typename... Args>
void for_each_range(Func func, Args&&... ranges)
{
    (func(ranges),...);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<float> weights = { 1.0f, 3.0f, 5.0f };
    std::vector<float> masks = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };

    for_each_range([](auto& v) { 
        std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 0.0f);
        }, weights, masks);

    std::ranges::copy
    (
        weights,
        std::ostream_iterator<float>{std::cout, ", "}
    );
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::ranges::copy
    (
        masks,
        std::ostream_iterator<float>{std::cout, ", "}
    );
    std::cout << '\n';
}

Demo.
I don't want to make it named lambda because I don't see any reason for code extraction (too many parameters will have to be passed and many of them will be updated) and it is hard to find good name for the fragment of code.
Is there a way to do this simpler, safer and more readable?
Or, maybe something already in place in std?
As a second thought, maybe it worth to std::view::zip vectors and unpack with std::get<n> (still not sure how to get the number of ranges in for_each_range in this case and get back from elements (tuples) to ranges. So, most likely this shouldn't work.

Don't make it a lambda, but a free function (with a name). Lambdas are a tool, not a must.

@PepijnKramer, my intention to avoid code extraction, as I stated in the question "because I don't see any reason for code extraction (too many parameters will have to be passed and many of them will be updated) and it is hard to find good name for the fragment of code". From my point of view, this reasoning covers all types of callable, regardless of their implementation (functions, lambdas, etc.). Please, correct me if I am wrong and if my reasoning somehow doesn't cover a free function.

You can definitely have the ranges be the first arguments and then the lambda (or some other callable) be the last argument.
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

auto getLast(auto&&... args) {
    return std::get<sizeof...(args) - 1>(std::make_tuple(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...));
}

void forEachRange(auto&&... args) {
    auto func = getLast(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);

    auto impl = [&func](auto& implRef, auto&& item, auto&&... remaining) {
        if constexpr (sizeof...(remaining) >= 1) {  // skip last element (callable)
            func(item);
            implRef(implRef, std::forward<decltype(remaining)>(remaining)...);
        }
    };

    impl(impl, std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
}

The getLast function pretty much does what it says. It returns the last element of a parameter pack using std::get with  std::make_tuple.
The forEachRange function first gets the last element, which is our callable. Then it recursively calls the impl lambda, consuming all arguments one by one, calling func with each argument, and skipping the last one, which again is the callable.
You could call the forEachRange function like the following:
std::vector<float> weights = { 1.0f, 3.0f, 5.0f };
std::vector<float> masks = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };

forEachRange(weights, masks, [](auto& v) {
    std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 0.0f);
});

live example

Don't you need std::forward<> in a couple of places?

you can get really close with std::tie
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

template<typename Func, typename... Args>
void for_each_range(std::tuple<Args&...> ranges, Func func)
{
    std::apply([&](auto&&...ranges)
    {
        (func(ranges),...);
    }, ranges);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<float> weights = { 1.0f, 3.0f, 5.0f };
    std::vector<float> masks = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };

    for_each_range(std::tie(weights, masks), [](auto& v) { 
        std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 0.0f);
        });

    std::ranges::copy
    (
        weights,
        std::ostream_iterator<float>{std::cout, ", "}
    );
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::ranges::copy
    (
        masks,
        std::ostream_iterator<float>{std::cout, ", "}
    );
    std::cout << '\n';
}

godbolt demo
unfortunately the compiler really doesn't like doing both template deduction and type deduction for the brace initializer, so i cannot get the compiler to produce code with just the braces.
you can add an overload for just 1 range when tie isn't needed.
template<std::ranges::range Range, typename Func>
void for_each_range(Range&& range, Func func)
{
    func(range);
}

